# How to set the font size of MenuItem in SWT?

Tags: java, fonts, swt

I want to change the font size of the `MenuItem` in SWT, there doesn't seem to be a obvious way to do it. Is there a work around for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MenuItem`s don't support fonts as you can see in [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=29899) bug report and apparently they don't want to implement it in the future:

> Sorry, we have no plans to do this.