# How to change the font size of Jface menu bar

Tags: jface

Im using Jface menu manager for creating menu bar for my application window, I am creating font but unable to set it to menu manager. How do I do this?

Comment: You can't change the font of the application menu bar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the font size of MenuItem in SWT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520157/how-to-set-the-font-size-of-menuitem-in-swt)